# Assemblies can't get resolved when getting them from NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-assembly

I have some annyoing problem which I can't figure out. I installed Visual Studio 2017 Community on a new laptop and loaded an project I made on my old one from TFS. Suddenly some of the references can't get resolved.

So I tried to create a complete fresh ASP.NET MVC Project and download some of the assemblies that don't work in the old project by NUGET. After downloading the references don't work. I get already the warning in VS. One of those assemblies that doesn't work is for example

> The referenced component 'System.Linq.Expressions' could not be found.

NUGET downloaded the assembly correctly and added the reference to the project. If I open the project file I find the entry for System.Linq.Expressions
and in HintPath: `..\packages\System.Linq.Expressions.4.3.0\lib\net463`.
That file definitely exists on the file system. I also tried to change to path to an absolute one manually with same result.

I am using the newest *.NET framework 4.7.2*

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Comment: AFAIK, Starting from .NET 4.5 and above,  this assembly `System.Linq.Expressions` is a .NET Framework assembly, we do not need add it by NuGet. How about manually add the reference from .NET Framework `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Facades`? I could not reproduce this issue with new fresh project, if you still have this issue, could you please share me a sample project by onedrive?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi Leo thanks for your help. You have been right with the Framework assembly. I actually never added those packages myself, it seems to me NUGET added them automatically at some point when I clicked in the NUGET manager Update all packages. On the other 2 computers this actually never made problems it works there also if the framework assemblies are added by NUGET. However on the new one it seems to be a problem when I add Framework references over NUGET. They can't be resolved no matter which. I uninstalled all those framework references from NUGET and the project compiles again.